# how to connect infoPath form with SQL server in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sql-server, sql-query

i have an BCS/external content type in SPD connected to my InfoPath form. I want to insert the data to the SQL table. Therefore, I just the following rules: **R1)** *Query using a data connection: Main connection*, **R2)** *Insert field value* for insert/submit command i used in the value field the following sql query

```
concat("ExecuteSqlQuery /dsname=SQLserverNameHere /sql=set DBnameHere off" INSERT INTO [dbo].[DBtableNameHere] ([ID], [First Name], [Last Name]) VALUES @ID, @FirstName, @LastName)
```

I would really appreasiete as much detail help as possible, thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: check your secure credentials for authentication based on the read and write user accounts set up in your SharePoint system.

Answer (score 0):

you can write web service for sql connection and deploy to sharepoint app pool in iis. then in infopath you can connect to this webservice. if you want you can pass parameters to webservice or get data from sql with webservice to infopath whatever you want.